# Entity framework, buffer between db model

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

I have data table `Groups` with columns: `Id` and `Name`. `Id` is an integer value between 1 and infinity. I can only read from table i cant save to it.

How to filter queries to db that if the entity asks for element with Id=0 i can give it manually? Is this even possible? I need this because i have virtual field of type Group which i use.

Comment: In the database you could build a view over the table which adds this dummy row. But it wouldn't be very performant and I'm guessing you can't create views. Otherwise

Comment: The reason I can't write in this table is that the it's content is synchronised with some other Db. I will look on this views feature.

Comment: Many problems looming. Should this null object be in the `Local` collection? If so, it should be attached, but never saved. If not, you may not always be able to use `Local`. Should it always be returned if *any* LINQ query could include 0 - like `where Id < 10`, or simpy `ToList` if the `DbSet` - or only if 0 is exclusively queried for? You'd have to dissect the expression. And then the technical challenges. You can't inherit from `DbSet` (not without implementing all its key methods yourself) and implementing `IDbSet` would probably not offer enough hooks.